# How do I add object to an array property of an anonymous object in c#

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, c#-6.0

Most of my studying of the c# was with the earlier releases I am not very familiar with this kind of code. I was provided with this snipped bellow but I am having a hard time to add the products dynamically to the items property of the anonymous object.

```
  var body = new
     {
        items = new[] {
         new {
            name = "Product 1",
            value = 1000,
            amount = 2
             }

           },
        shippings = new[] {
           new {
            name = "Default Shipping Cost",
            value = 100
               }
             }
      };
```

The idea would be:

```
 var body = new { items =  new[]{ new { }  } };

        foreach(Modelos.Produto p in carrinho.Items)
        {
            body.items // add elements  { name = p.name }
        }
```

Comment: You can't add elements to an array without recreating it. You should be using a List.

Comment: What is `new { items =  new[]{ new { }  } };` supposed to produce? An anonymous object that has an array of anonymous objects? I don't see the point of such illegibility, I'd keep it to using classes for something like this

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: It can be useful as a simple way of generating one-off JSON in my experience. It's not that the *object* is anonymous though - it's the *type* that's anonymous.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Not sure what part of my comment makes it look like I said that the object is anonymous

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: "An anonymous object that has an array of anonymous objects" It's an object of an anonymous type, that has an array with an anonymous type as the element type.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
var body = new { items =  new[]{ new { }  }.ToList() };

foreach(Modelos.Produto p in carrinho.Items)
{
    body.items.Add( /* ... */ );
}
```

But note this coding is style is intended to solve some very specific problems, namely working with old COM libraries and inside LinQ queries. You'll quickly find it has significant drawbacks if you try to move much beyond that.

One of those drawbacks (I'd call it a feature) is you're still working with fixed types, meaning the `new { }` inside that collection initializer became the template for the generic list.

Comment: What would be the point of this, though? Since `items` holds empty anonymous types, you cannot add anything *useful* to that list, or am I missing something?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: You can add another instance of the same anonymous type. So long as you use the same property names and types, in the same order, that would refer to the same type.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes, I know that, and that's exactly why I commented. Having a list of `empty anonymous type` means you can only add more `empty anonymous type` (VS gives it this special name)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I was assuming that Joel's answer just omitted the part in the initial `body` assignment specifying the properties - that it would be the same as in the question, but with the `ToList()` part. Basically emphasizing just that you're creating a list, because then you can add to it. It would definitely be helpful for Joel to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have no other choice, and I **strongly** advise to use something else instead (`List<T>` etc.), you could use `Array.Resize()` to resize the array and add a new item at its end:

```
var body = new { items =  new[]{ new { }  } };

foreach(Modelos.Produto p in carrinho.Items)
{
     var array = body.items;
     Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);
     body.items[body.items.Length - 1] = new {}; // or whatever you want to add here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<Test>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Test($"descrition {i}"));
        }

        var listDynamic = new List<object>();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
            object expando = new ExpandoObject();
            var p = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var value = item.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(item, null);

                p[property.Name] = value;
            }

            listDynamic.Add(p);
        }
```

I think this solve your problem.